# Save a video in video folder wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a small app for recording movies and at the same time record data from gps and accelerometer in to a file. My first thought was to use a lens but they only seems to be for photos so I created my own recording app. But as I need to copy the recorded movies and data file to a computer afterward I feel that the isolated storage is not that good of a solution even tho it works with windows phone Power Tools.

Is there any way that I could record a Movie and store it in the video folder and at the same time record gps? The gps data can be solved in many ways like email, skydrive etc but the Movie will become to big to upload.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is no way to save video to the phone's media library. You'll have to integrate SkyDrive or have your own server get the video from the app's isolated storage